# force merging a dev branch to master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

My project is over and I worked on a dev branch called `symfony`. This branch is my new master and I want to merge it to master.

I would like to erase `master` and copy `symfony` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to *not* include any of the changes from `master`, but just "close" it and keep going with exactly what you have in `symfony`. If so, use the `ours` [merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies), which will create a merge commit without incorporating any of the changes from the other branch and thus effectively "close" the other branch. The last two commands simply rearrange the branch names.

```
git checkout symfony
git merge -s ours master
git checkout -B master
git branch -D symfony
```